# How to translate form errors with angular i18n?

Tags: forms, angular, validation, internationalization

I am working on i18n for angular and I would like to provide a translation for form errors. But I do not know how to do that. I followed the guide from [angular website](https://angular.io/guide/i18n). And I tried to use the select method but it is not working.

Initially, before trying to translate, I had the following code in my component.ts:

```
onValueChanged(data?: any) {
  if (!this.userForm) { return; }
  const form = this.userForm;

  for (const field in this.formErrors) {
    // clear previous error message (if any)
    this.formErrors[field] = '';
    const control = form.get(field);

    if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
      const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
      for (const key in control.errors) {
        this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
      }
    }
  }
}

formErrors = {
  'firstname': ''
};

validationMessages = {
   'firstname': {
     'required': 'Firstname is required.',
     'pattern': 'Only alphabetics caracters are allowed.'
   }
};
```

And the following code in my component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="formErrors.firstname" class="form-control-feedback alert">
  {{ formErrors.firstname }}
</div>
```

It worked perfectly because there was no translation. Then, I made the following updates:

In the component.ts:

```
validationMessages = {
  'firstname': {
    'required': 'required',
    'pattern': 'pattern'
  }
};
```

In the component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="formErrors.firstname" class="form-control-feedback alert">
  <ng-container i18n="@@userModalFirstnameError">
    {formErrors.firstname, select, required {required} pattern {pattern}}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

In the messages.fr.xlf file, I have this:

```
<trans-unit id="userModalFirstnameError" datatype="html">
  <source>{VAR_SELECT, select, required {required} pattern {pattern} }</source>
  <target>
    {VAR_SELECT, select, required {Nom utilisateur obligatoire} pattern {pattern}}
  </target>
  ...
</trans-unit>
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not work.

Comment: Am I the only one with this kind of requirement? Any idea would be very appreciated !! :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally found where the issue comes from. Actually, there were 2 mistakes.

1. The first one is related to the 'VAR_SELECT' in the .xlf file. It has been generated by Angular with the build command => "ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xlf". This 'VAR_SELECT' works well if a "direct" variable is used (for example if I put "{toto, select, required {required} pattern {pattern}}" and toto was equal to "required"). But it seems that it does not work if a variable from table is used (which is my case with the variable "formErrors.firstname"). So I replaced 'VAR_SELECT' in the .xlf file by the name of my variable 'formErrors.firstname'.
2. The second one is in the "onValueChanged" function:

   ```
   for (const key in control.errors) {
     this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
   }
   ```

   Because of the space character at the end, the variable did not match one of the values defined (for example, it was 'required ' where I was expected 'required'. Note the additional space at the end of the 1st value)